# In how many ways one or two batters can score at least 6 runs in 6 deliveries to win a match?

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can someone (or two persons) score at least 6 in 6 balls/deliveries?

Rules: There is a possibility of scoring 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or maximum 6 from one balls/deliveries. Each delivery is valid (no extra delivery). When total score is 6 or more, game over (no need to score even if there are deliveries left).

For example: Possible ways: [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4], [6], [1, 1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6] and so many.

[0, 3, 4, 5] is not a proper way as score 6 achieved at 3rd ball.

Could you please help me to find the answer mathematically? Thanks.

Comment: If we insert trailing zeros when the score has been achieved before six balls are up, then we are looking at six-tuples $(x_1,...,x_6)$ of numbers from $0,1,...,6$ which sum to any of $6,7,8,9,10,11$. Is this statement clear? It will also be helpful if you state the answer you got from your program.

Comment: Oh , I see. Can you edit your post and insert that information? What I think : you'll still have to go case-by-case, and it's not going to be very easy mathematically. You can get symbols and formulas, but exact calculations are probably going to take a lot of computational effort. You can also reply regarding my mathematical formulation of your statement, and whether you understood it or not. Thanks

Comment: Some hints will be good, I know how permutations combinations work.

Comment: Great : you can add that to the question post as well. So for example, looking at just $x_1+...+x_6 = 6$, we are now only looking at non-negative tuples summing to $6$. So the answer for : how many ways can you hit exactly $6$ in $6$ balls? would be $\binom{6+6-1}{6-1} = \binom{11}{5} = 462$. Now, if you want $7$ instead of $6$, then you can repeat this, except you'll have to remove all cases where you get single entry of $7$.  That then extends to $8$ etc.

Comment: If somebody requests for it, you can also add/link the code of the program you wrote so they can test it for themselves. Good luck with the arithmetic as we approach the higher numbers, though!

Comment: Not exactly 6, The game allows more than 6 when the score was less than 6 at the beginning of the delivery. Say, 2, 0, 3, 4 is a valid way.

Comment: No I understood that @abhimanyue I only calculated the case where the total reached is *exactly* $6$. It could easily be more , as you illustrate. It could be $9$, like with $2,0,3,4,0,0$. That will have to be counted more carefully and separately, so I'm just leaving some hints which others/you can look at.

Comment: [0, 3, 4, 5] is invalid since [0, 3, 4] already sums up to 7 (we need 6), so game over, no need to score anymore.

Comment: Understood : and it won't be included either. We will disallow sums above $11$ : if $12$ was reached then $6$ had to be reached before it. For $11$, an argument could be as follows : it has to finish with a $6$, and the rest can add up to five in any number of ways with any number of variables. That is a lot of cases and a lot of computation, though. Similar arguments can be made for $10,9,8$ etc.

Comment: Let $r_{i,j}$ be the number of ways of scoring at least $i$ in $j$ deliveries and $d_{i,j}$ the number of ways of scoring exactly $i$ in $j$ deliveries. Then these obey the recurrence $r_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^6 d_{(i-k),j-1} (6-k + 1)$, $d_{(i,j)} = \sum_{k=0}^6 d_{(i-k),j-1}$, so it comes down to computing the $d_{i,j}$ , for which small base cases can be computed explicitly. This isn't what you wanted but I leave it here in case its helpful to someone who wants to exploit it.

Comment: Should this have a "cricket" tag? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After $k-1$ deliveries there are $\binom{k+4}{5}$ ways to have fewer than 6 runs scored so far.  There are 7 times as many possibilities after the next delivery, of which $\binom{k+5}{5}$ still have fewer than 6 runs scored.  Therefore there are $7\binom{k+4}{5}-\binom{k+5}{5}$ ways that end on delivery $k$.  Summing this from $k=1$ to $n$ yields $f(n) = 1 + 7 \binom{n+5}{6} - \binom{n+6}{6}$ possibilities with up to $n$ deliveries.  $f(6) = 2311$.

Comment: I don't get it quietly, could you please explain little more. I don't understand first two lines. @Jim Ferry

Comment: For $j<6$ the number of ways to get exactly $j$ runs in $k$ deliveries is $\binom{k+j-1}{j}$. Cf. the "stars and bars" technique. The sum of this from $j=0$ to $r$ is $\binom{k+r}{r}$. Cf. the "hockey-stick" identity. This is the number of ways to get at most $r$ runs in $k$ deliveries. So $\binom{k+5}{5}$ is the number of ways to score fewer than 6 runs in $k$ deliveries. Thus, $\binom{k+4}{5}$ ways in $k-1$. Multiplying by 7 (for the next delivery) and subtracting $\binom{k+5}{5}$ (the cases with $<6$ runs) counts the number of cases that end at step $k$. Use hockey stick to sum. @abhimanyue